# How to create a dependent dropdown in MVC c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, crud

I have created a single dropdown using ViewBag function . I want to pass id of selected option(in dropdown) in such that the dropdown populates which corresponds to that id . 
dropdown 1 being States 2 being City . When user selects a State , City should be populated in other dropdown . There are various methods I saw on internet (jquery ) but I want to implement using this method . In database I have linked both  city and state tables using foreign key references.

```
 public ActionResult AddEmployees()
    {            
    Employees obj = new Employees();
    List<ViewAllStates_Result> list = new List<ViewAllStates_Result>();
    list = objmodel.ViewAllStates().ToList();
    ViewBag.State = list;         
    return View(obj);
    }
```

and in View page

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.States,new 
    SelectList(ViewBag.State,"Statename","Statename"))
```

Comment: Suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want jquery then you can do it with javascript :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.States,new 
SelectList(ViewBag.State,"Statename","Statename"),
new { @onchange="CallChangefunc(this.value)" })

<script>
function CallChangefunc(val)
{
  //call the controller method
}
</script>
```

Comment: which controller method shoudl be called there?? "View City by State" this method??

Comment: The method that'll assign the corresponding city collection to the second dropdown.

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.States,new 
    SelectList(ViewBag.State,"Stateid", "States"),new {@id="ddlstates", 
    @onchange = "CallChangefunc(this.value)" }) This is in my view

Comment: What's your query?